# find all subsequences whose sum lies between a to b

Tags: c++, recursion, c++17, dynamic-programming, subsequence

How do i find all subsequences whose sum lies between a to b efficiently? I tried the general method of first creating subsequences and then checking the condition if it exists between a and b or not.
Here's my try.

can i also optimize it? in case i dont want them printed.(as in case of printing it will only give complexity of O(n^3)

```
void printSubinrng(vector < int > arr, int n, int a, int b) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  {
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sum <= a && sum >= b) 
    {
      cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
  }
}

void printSubsequences(vector < int > arr, int index, int a, int b, vector < int > subarr) {
  if (index == arr.size()) {
    int l = subarr.size();
    if (l != 0)
      printSubinrng(subarr, l, a, b);
  } else {
    printSubsequences(arr, index + 1, a, b, subarr);
    subarr.push_back(arr[index]);
    printSubsequences(arr, index + 1, a, b, subarr);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Based on your English description, I'm not sure where O(n^3) comes from. For a sequence of length n, there are O(2^n) subsequences, as each element of the sequence can either be in the sequence, or not in the sequence. Unless you mean substring / contiguous subsequence?

Comment: Assuming we're working with contiguous subsequences, you might be able to improve your efficiency by using [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum). After applying `partial_sum`, you can find the sum of elements in a subrange by subtracting two integers. That would let you get to O(n^2)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Question seems pretty clear but adding a few expected/actual sample output calls and expected input size constraints (if available) would be nice.